# FFMpeg: merge images with audio for specific duration

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have been working on `FFMpeg` from past 7 days. I am required to create a video where I need to perform following:

1. `Concat` few images into video picked from android storage.
2. `Add a music` file [same picked from android storage].
3. `Set Duration per image` to be shown in the video. e.g. if 3 images are picked then total duration of video should be 3*duration choosen by user.

**What I have done so far.**

I am using `implementation 'nl.bravobit:android-ffmpeg:1.1.5'` for the `FFmpeg` prebuild binaries.
Following is the command that has been used to concatenation the images and set the duration:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/duration_selected_by_user -f concat -safe 0 -i path_of_concat_file.txt -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p path_of_output_video_file.mp4
```

Note:

1. By adding the duration chosen by a user as frame rate I am able to set the duration of each image to be shown.
2. Concat work well and images are merged to for the video.

**Problem:**
When I try to add audio in the same process, progress run for a long time even for small audio by using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/duration_selected_by_user -i path_of_audio_file.mp3 -f concat -safe 0 -i path_of_concat_file.txt -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p path_of_output_video_file.mp4
```

It looks like there is some issue in command as I am not much familiar and experienced with the technology. How can I improve the performance of merging images and audio to get the better results?

*Important Links related to context:*

https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android

Comment: Try adding `-preset ultrafast` after `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HB mentioned in the comments:

> Try adding -preset ultrafast after -pix_fmt yuv420p

A `preset` is a collection of options that will provide a certain **encoding speed to compression ratio**. A slower preset will provide better compression (compression is quality per filesize). This means that, for example, if you target a certain file size or constant bit rate, you will achieve better quality with a slower preset. Similarly, for constant quality encoding, you will simply save bitrate by choosing a slower preset.
 The available presets in descending order of speed are:

- ultrafast
- superfast
- veryfast
- faster
- fast
- medium – default preset
- slow
- slower
- veryslow
- placebo – ignore this as it is not useful

Reference: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Preset