# FFMpeg: Add background image during the process of video creation

Tags: android, ffmpeg, media, video-processing

In reference to my previous question [FFMpeg: merge images with audio for specific duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156379/ffmpeg-merge-images-with-audio-for-specific-duration) I have successfully merged few images with audio for specific duration by using following command.

```
ffmpeg \
-y \
-f concat \
-safe 0 \
-r 1/5 \
-i concat.txt \
-i audio.ogg \
-c:v libx264 \
-profile:v high \
-crf 17 \
-preset ultrafast \
-strict experimental \
-t 15 \
output.mp4
```

In order to add a background image, I tried to use https://superuser.com/a/876275/299733 and other solutions that exist on the web. But the given solution doesn't overlay my images properly and I was getting black video throughout the duration. Therefore, I encode the resultant video from earlier command once again via :

```
ffmpeg \
-y \
-loop 1 \
-i bg.jpg \
-i output.mp4 \
-filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,format=yuv420p" \
-c:v libx264 \
-profile:v high \
-crf 17 \
-preset ultrafast \
-strict experimental \
-t 15 \
output2.mp4
```

Now, I am able to get the desired result. Is there any way to merge both requests into a single pass? Or a better way without loss of any performance?

**Additional details:**

*concat.txt*

```
file '/home/shubham/Desktop/FFMpeg/image_1.jpg'
file '/home/shubham/Desktop/FFMpeg/image_2.jpg'
file '/home/shubham/Desktop/FFMpeg/image_3.jpg'
```

**Based on @gyan response**

Updated concat.xml:

```
file '/home/shubham/Desktop/FFMpeg/image_4.jpg'
duration 5
file '/home/shubham/Desktop/FFMpeg/image_5.jpg'
duration 5
file '/home/shubham/Desktop/FFMpeg/image_6.jpg'
duration 5
file '/home/shubham/Desktop/FFMpeg/image_6.jpg'
```

Updated Command:

```
ffmpeg \
-y \
-loop 1 \
-i bg.jpg \
-f concat \
-safe 0 \
-i concat.txt \
-i audio.ogg \
-filter_complex "[1]fps=25[v];[0][v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,format=yuv420p" \
-c:v libx264 \
-profile:v high \
-crf 17 \
-preset ultrafast \
-strict experimental \
-t 15 \
output.mp4
```

The problem is that when images are of different resolution or even for the same resolution the images are skipped. And most of the times last image is shown. However, there are no criteria of which image is selected and which one is skipped.
SAMPLE:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JxCsV2eudKzdgWWuefXqdaWPaBf9Dzzd/view?usp=sharing

However, if I repeatedly used the same image or copy the image and rename it. In both the cases, I get proper images on the background without any skipping.

**EDIT: 09 JULY 2018**

As @gyan stated in comments: *Convert each image to same resolution and type.*
I check the info of images. via

```
 ffmpeg -i image_X.jpg
```

And found out two images have different encoding:

Image 1: *Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480 [SAR 72:72 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc*

Image 2: *Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480 [SAR 72:72 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc*

Which is the possible cause of the failure in merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg \
-y \
-loop 1 \
-i bg.jpg \
-f concat \
-safe 0 \
-r 1/5 \
-i concat.txt \
-i audio.ogg \
-filter_complex "[1]fps=25[v];[0][v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,format=yuv420p" \
-c:v libx264 \
-profile:v high \
-crf 17 \
-preset ultrafast \
-strict experimental \
-t 15 \
output.mp4
```

The concat demuxer registers the properties of its first input, like codec, resolution, timebase..etc as its demuxed stream  property. So, for reliable results, all inputs should have the same properties.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I get the same black video frame throughout the application as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Remove the `-r 1/5` and in the text file, after each file entry, add on the next line, `duration 5`. Also duplicate the last file entry and add it as the last line.

Comment: Thanks again. As ffmpeg is not a conventional programming it will take a little time for me to get exactly command are working especially filter_complex. Can you please have a look at the edit. Few images are skipped uncertainly.

Comment: All inputs to concat demuxer have to have same properties: codec, resolution..etc.

Comment: Would you like to recommend me a solution for this situation?

Comment: Convert each image to same resolution and type.

Comment: can you recommend me a link to some solution for merging image of different formats or transcoding image or update the answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: A batch/script to convert each image to the same type.